# DDS Fast-RTPS HelloWorldExampleTCP one Publisher to two Subscribers

Tags: data-distribution-service

I'm new to Fast-RTPS.
I would like to use HelloWorldExampleTCP to run a publisher to publish messages to two subscribers. I started two subscribers node in pc1 and then start a publisher in pc0.

The expected result should be: both subscribers received messages sent from publisher.
But the actual result is, only one subscriber received the messages.

[image]

Any comment will be appreciated.

Kevin Kuei

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the second subscriber doesn't get in time to receive the messages. 
If I set -s 1000 in publisher, the second subscriber will receive the messages.

Kevin Kuei